# Flink SQL Result field does not match requested type error on LocalDateTime

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

When i group the below select it getting type maching error. I already try to CAST as TIMESTAMP and try to change POJOs LocalDateTime type. Most of the sample codes converts as Row.class could not find any custom class example.

`SELECT name, MIN(price) AS minPrice, MAX(price) AS maxPrice, AVG(price) AS avarage, COUNT(name) as sayi, TUMBLE_START(rowtime, INTERVAL '5' SECOND) AS zaman FROM STOCK GROUP BY TUMBLE(rowtime, INTERVAL '5' SECOND), name`

Thrown Error:

`Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: Result field 'zaman' does not match requested type. Requested: GenericType<java.time.LocalDateTime>; Actual: LocalDateTime`

Code:

```
    tableEnvironment.registerDataStream("STOCK", messageStream, "name, price, rowtime.rowtime");

    Table result = tableEnvironment.sqlQuery(
            "SELECT name, MIN(price) AS minPrice, MAX(price) AS maxPrice, AVG(price) AS avarage, COUNT(name) as sayi, TUMBLE_START(rowtime, INTERVAL '5' SECOND) AS zaman FROM STOCK GROUP BY TUMBLE(rowtime, INTERVAL '5' SECOND), name");

    result.printSchema();

    FlinkKafkaProducer011<String> myProducer = new FlinkKafkaProducer011<String>(kp.getProducerProperties().getProperty(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG),
            "STOCKGROUP", new SimpleStringSchema());

    myProducer.setWriteTimestampToKafka(true);

    DataStream<Tuple2<Boolean, StockGroup>> stream = tableEnvironment.toRetractStream(result, StockGroup.class);

    stream.map(x -> x.f1.toString()).addSink(myProducer);
```

StockGroup.class POJO;

```
public String name;
public Double minPrice;
public Double maxPrice;
public Double avarage;
public Long sayi;
public LocalDateTime zaman;
```

Printed Schema;

```
root
 |-- name: STRING
 |-- minPrice: DOUBLE
 |-- maxPrice: DOUBLE
 |-- avarage: DOUBLE
 |-- sayi: BIGINT NOT NULL
 |-- zaman: TIMESTAMP(3) *ROWTIME*
```

Comment: Can you provide the fully qualified type name of `zaman`?

Comment: Hi @ArvidHeise do you mean Pojos public LocalDateTime zaman;

Comment: What is the fully qualified type of zaman? java.time.LocalDateTime or org.joda.time.LocalDateTime?

Comment: @ArvidHeise  java.time.LocalDateTime library.